# Using default values for mysqli constructor fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to connect to a database using the default values for the [mysqli constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), which is documented to be:

- host = `ini_get("mysqli.default_host")`
- username = `ini_get("mysqli.default_user")`
- passwd = `ini_get("mysqli.default_pw")`

The reason I want to use the defaults is so I can have the credentials in the config file instead of scattered through my code.  However, when I pass no values, the connection succeeds but then subsequent queries fail with no error.

```
$db = new mysqli();
if ($db->connect_errno) die("Connect failed: " . $db->connect_error);
if ($rs = $db->query("select user();") or die("Query failed: " . $db->error)) {
  $row = $rs->fetch_row();
  echo $row[0];
  $rs->close();
}
```

This outputs:

> Query failed:

That means the connection succeeded, but any query fails with an error.  (Other actions, such as `select_db`, fail the same way.)

Interestingly, I can fix it by changing the first line to:

```
$db = new mysqli(ini_get("mysqli.default_host"),
                 ini_get("mysqli.default_user"),
                 ini_get("mysqli.default_pw"));
```

... but I'd prefer to not have to type out the default values everywhere I need a database connection.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to use the `mysqli` constructor with no arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing this question, I happened to scroll down the documentation page and noted the following:

> Note: Calling the constructor with no parameters is the same as calling `mysqli_init()`.

Looking up the [mysqli_init documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php), it says:

> Note: Any subsequent calls to any mysqli function (except `mysqli_options()`) will fail until `mysqli_real_connect()` was called.

Therefore, the fix is to change the first line from:

```
$db = new mysqli();
```

To:

```
$db = new mysqli();
$db->real_connect();
```

I would have expected in that scenario that `mysqli_error` would have returned something like "not connected" instead of an empty string.  That's a bit counter-intuitive, but at least it's somewhat documented.